# Application are expected to add rootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I am creating a file when the app is activated. On the basis, of the presence of that file different views get loaded.

I am trying is

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    if(condition true)
    {
        //[window addSubview:viewController.view];
        [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }else{
        //[window addSubview:signViewController.view];
        [self.window setRootViewController:secondViewController];
        [window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }

   // return YES;
}
```

Error I am getting is `Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch`

Comment: What is the content of your main.m file.This error can also be caused because of that.please post the code of main.m file

Comment: Are you sure that viewController or secondViewController respectively is not nil? Set an NSLog or breakpoint to figure out whether they are properly set at that point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should firstly `alloc` and `init` your view controller before you use it.

```
if(condition true)
{
    //[window addSubview:viewController.view];
    viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}else{
    //[window addSubview:signViewController.view];
    secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:secondViewController];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just write

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

after **else** or before **}**

Comment: He could do that for better style and readability of the code. But that would not do any change to the execution of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have alloc and init for view controller.
use
viewController=[[ViewControllerName alloc]init];

I got same error when my viewController was not allocated.